# Variable assignment of anonymous function returns null

Tags: php

I have the following lines of code in my application:

```
$d = function(){
    return 5;
};
var_dump($d, gettype($d));
exit;
```

When I execute this code in my application it outputs:

```
NULL string(4) "NULL"
```

This surprises me, how can $d by NULL after it has been assigned an anonymous function?

When I run the exact same code in a separate PHP file on the same webserver under the same vhost / config it outputs:

```
object(Closure)#1 (0) {} string(6) "object"
```

So it seems to be something with my PHP application which is built with Zend Framework. But I can't understand what my application could have done to mess up this core behavior. I am experiencing this problem with PHP 5.3.2 on CentOS 5.8. Any directions on whats going on here are welcome since I'm all out of ideas on this one.

Edit: Also when trying to running `$d()` in the non-working case PHP says:

```
Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /Bootstrap.php on line 118
```

Strange wording of the error since the language now accepts anonymous functions, but this code gives me te same error so it seems to be the correct message:

```
$a = null;
$a();
```

Comment: You sure you run php5.3 on both vhosts?

Comment: Yes, there is only one vhost. The file in which it works is right next to the file that does not work.

Comment: Oh, I see I misread, my bad, I'm out of ideas then O_O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so the key part of information that I forgot to provide (or essentially missed while debugging) is that in my application the non-working closure is the second closure in the execution of the script. In my demo code the closure is the first closure in the script and therefor working. There seems to be a problem with my version / build of PHP and multiple closures. For the record these are this is the version information of PHP on which I am experiencing this problem:

```
PHP Version => 5.3.2
System => Linux ip-172-31-15-243 2.6.18-308.16.1.el5.centos.plusxen #1 SMP Tue Oct 2     23:25:27 EDT 2012 x86_64
Build Date => Jun  6 2013 09:58:54
```

The following code provides a good test:

```
$closures[] = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++) {
    $closures[$x] = function() use($x) {
        return $x * 2;
    };
}
var_dump($closures);
```

On the broken PHP 5.3.2 this outputs:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  NULL
  [1]=>
  NULL
  [2]=>
  NULL
  [3]=>
  NULL
  [4]=>
  NULL
}
```

On PHP 5.4.24 on my MacBook this outputs:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(Closure)#1 (1) {
    ["static"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["x"]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  object(Closure)#2 (1) {
    ["static"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["x"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  object(Closure)#3 (1) {
    ["static"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["x"]=>
      int(2)
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  object(Closure)#4 (1) {
    ["static"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["x"]=>
      int(3)
    }
  }
  [4]=>
  object(Closure)#5 (1) {
    ["static"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["x"]=>
      int(4)
    }
  }
}
```

To make matters even stranger, when I run the script on the command line with the php command the output is correct. When I run the the script via the php-cgi command (which is used by the webserver) the output is wrong. So for now this problem seems to have to do with php-cgi.

Edit:

**The solution:** eAccelerator is the problem here. I'm using eAccelerator v0.9.6, when this extension is disabled everything works as expected. When this extension is enabled the callable are NULL. See [eAccelerator issue at Github repo](https://github.com/eaccelerator/eaccelerator/issues/12).

Comment: I recommend you move your actual solution (eAccelerator) to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
    function abc (){
        return 5;
    };
    $d =abc(); 

    var_dump($d);
    exit;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for editing the code but I don't want to run the function, I want a callable that can be passed to be ran at a later moment. Ultimately what I'm doing is implementing this: http://tech.vg.no/2012/06/01/lazy-loading-resources-with-zend-framework-bootstrap/ .

Answer (score 0):

May be you have an old `php`. Upgrade it please.

I have next result:

```
class Closure#1 (0) {
}
string(6) "object"
```

Comment: Something indeed seems to be wrong with the code. It seems that only the first closuure that is defined in the code works. What I forgot to mention is that there is a working closure earlier in the code. When I put two closures in the dome code, the second one also doesn't work. Also, the problem only happens when using php-cgi and not when using the php binary itself.